# How to handle conditional popups from application using codedui?

Tags: .net, coded-ui-tests, automated-tests

Recoded many automated test cases in CodedUI using VS 2010, 
But there are many popups are coming based on flow of the system, as those are not recorded test will stuck and fail...

Is there any way we can have generic function to handle all the popups coming across while test is running?

Comment: If you are not happy with the recording workflow. You can capture the objects and code the steps. This way you will have more control than recorded sessions

Answer (score 1):

Two main options. You can write code to expect the popups and handle then but not fail if they do not occur. Do this by wrapping the code in assignments to `Playback.PlaybackSettings.ContinueOnError`. But this may not be appropriate for your question.

Another approach is to add some retry code. When a step fails Coded UI can call an error handler which can attempt to dismiss the popup and then retry the action that failed. Do this by adding an event handler to `Playback.PlaybackError`. An event handler might just set the faling item to be tried again and then calling `Keyboard.SendKeys("{Enter}");` to try and dismiss the popup. For full details see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/11/20/retrying-failed-playback-actions-with-coded-ui.aspx

Comment: Hi AdrianHHH
Thank you very much for your solution, But I'm not able to get add the event Playback.PlaybackError in vs 2010. also the article is implemented using VS 2012. 
Please suggest how to I can add this event.

Comment: I think that the `Playback.PlaybackError` is only available in Visual Studio 2012 and later. I doubt whether it can be added to the 2010 version.